# json-server running but can't access its api due to 403

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json-server

Learning reactjs, trying to simulate a server with [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)
this is my script to run the server:

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 5000"
},
```

running this on terminal `npm run server`
output:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61616/507f7893-92a9-4526-b8f4-a3e71cfa4c62
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.

> my-app@0.1.0 server
> json-server --watch db.json --port 5000

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61629/8a2f877f-f4bd-465e-b454-01a63eabb40a
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:5000/tasks

  Home
  http://localhost:5000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
  Watching...
```

now when I try to access http://localhost:5000/tasks , I get 403 Access to localhost was denied.
what can I do to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: could you please put routes.json and db.json files here?

Comment: when open `http://localhost:5000` in browser what is see?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem was with the port. changed it to 3001 and it works.
still doesn't understand why did this happen in that port.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you are using MacOS Monterey(or maybe other versions in the future). Check the reason here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Cause: Control Center on Monterey listening to port 5000 and port 7000

Fix: change the port to avoid range 5000-7000, like following,

```rb
"server": "json-server --watch db.json --port 3000"
```

or just remove the customised argument `--port 3000` as this is the default value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Search for AirPlay receiver and uncheck it if you are a mac user. Worked for me on port 5000.

Reason - This is apparently due to the new AirPlay functionality. Control Center stops listening to those ports when I turn off “AirPlay Receiver” in the “Sharing” System Preference:

Source- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332